# Procedimientos almacenados en Controlador Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, stored-procedure, controller

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que edita un registro, el campo fecha es con un `getdate()`, estoy intentando usar ese procedimiento en mi controlador pero me sale un error.

> No se ha dado ningun argumento correpondiente al parametro formal
>   requerido

y creo que podria tener algo que ver con la fecha

```
[HttpPost]                                                                      
   public ActionResult Edit (double id, FormCollection collection) 
     try{                                                                     
       testsp usr =db.spelegirid(id).First();                                           
       if(ModelState.IsValid){
   db.insertproceso(id,collection["id,material,proceso,encargado,fechafinal"]); 
     }
```

Comment: claramente el error dice que no le estas dando argumentos a la llamada del procedimiento almacenado. si vas a agregar/quitar parámetros de un procedimiento, debes actualizar el modelo del procedimiento

Comment: pero todos esos argumentos si estan en el store, excepto el de fechafinal pero ya se lo quite y sigue el error

Comment: por eso, tienes que actualizar el modelo del SP, tu proyecto es de visual studio?

Comment: Si visual studio asp.net mvc, este el el modelo del store                                  public virtual int insertproceso(Nullable<double> id,string material,string proceso, string encargado)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si añades o Quitas argumentos en un procedimiento almacenado de SQL ya agregado anteriormente a tu modelo en tu proyecto, debes eliminar sus referencias y volver a actualizar tu modelo(agregar nuevamente el SP)

**Abrir modelo de datos de proyecto**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Quitar modelo del Procedimiento almacenado**
(Se debe quitar de los 3 contenedores señalados, en tipos complejos, suele agregarse un '_Result' al nombre de tu SP)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**volver a agregar tu SP al modelo**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realiza estos pasos y me avisas como te va ;)

**Breakpoint VS**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El breakpoint o punto de interrupción sirve para llevar una traza de lo que hace tu código, es de gran utilidad al momento de querer revisar si algun paso se esta ejecutando de manera correcta, como muestra la siguiente foto, puedes colocar un punto en donde quieras pausar la ejecución(Flecha roja).
Al momento de ejecutar, la ejecución se pausara en donde indicaste el punto, con el mouse puedes revisar los valores de las variables.

1. con F5 reanudas la ejecucion
2. con F10 avanzas a la siguiente linea
3. F11 te permite avanzar o entrar dentro de una funcion o rutina(siempre y cuando exista una en la linea de ejecución en la que te encuentras)

Comment: Ya realice los pasos compañero y me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: :( y al ejecutar el SP en SQL no te genera errores? lo otro que puedes hacer es usar un punto de interrupción al momento de hacer la ejecución del SP, y revisar el estado de las variables @senseilex

Comment: En sql si jala perfecto :( , como hago eso compañero?

Comment: @senseilex editare la respuesta, agregare como colocar el punto de interrupción

Comment: Disculpa compañero ya puse el punto de interrupcion pero tengo que coompilarlo de diferente manera?, porque no se puede compilar con el error

Comment: nono, es de la misma forma. como estas invocando la ejecucion del sp, puedes editar la pregunta agregando tu codigo?

Comment: [HttpPost] public ActionResult Edit (double id, FormCollection collection) try{ testsp usr =db.spelegirid(id).First(); if(ModelState.IsValid){ db.insertproceso (id,collection["id,material,proceso,encargado,fechafinal"]); }                             return RedirecToAction("Index");}